# Etymology of wasteweir?

Tags: etymology

I would guess that this word is derived from waste (english) + weir (german)? Can anyone provide a more definitive derivation explanation? (couldn't find anything via etymonline.com) Will keep googling for more info and update if I find anything interesting.

Comment: I believe 'weir' is also an English word.

Comment: ya, I was just totally guessing. :)

Comment: Nice guess, the word 'weir' looks really weird.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are the etymologies:

> "waste" is a derivative from the Latin word *vāstus*.
>
> "Weir" comes from the Old English word `wer`, to dam up. `Wer` in turns come from the German word `Wehr`.

So actually its "waste"(Latin) + "weir"(German)

Comment: The sources I have looked at indicate that "weir" is not from German "Wehr." Instead, the two words are cognate: both of them descend from a common ancestor in the older language from which both English and German are descended.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to split up the terms and search for them individually:

*[waste](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=waste&searchmode=none)*:

> c.1200, "desolate regions," from O.Fr. wast, from L. vastum, neut. of vastus "waste" (see waste (v.)); replacing O.E. westen, woesten "a desert, wilderness," from the Latin word. Meaning "useless expenditure" is recorded from c.1300; sense of "refuse matter" is attested from early 15c. Waste basket first recorded 1850. Waste-paper first recorded 1580s.

*[weir](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=weir&searchmode=none)*:

> O.E. wer "dam, fence, enclosure," especially one for catching fish (related to werian "dam up"), from P.Gmc. *warjanan (cf. O.N. ver, O.Fris., M.Du. were, Du. weer, O.H.G. wari, Ger. Wehr "defense, protection," Goth. warjan "to defend, protect"), from PIE *wer- "to cover, shut" (cf. Skt. vatah "enclosure," vrnoti "covers, wraps, shuts;" Lith. uzveriu "to shut, to close;" O.Pers. *pari-varaka "protective;" L. (op)erire "to cover;" O.C.S. vora "sealed, closed," vreti "shut;" O.Ir. feronn "field," prop. "enclosed land")

So you were right Jamie, *weir* is primarily from Old English, but as you can see from the lengthy etymology, it also may have been derived from proto-Germanic, Latin, Sanskrit, Old Persian and number of other languages.

Comment: FWIW, the word ‘waste-weir’ is mentioned in the OED under ‘waste’. It doesn't provide any etymology, but provides three citations, dated 1793, 1840, and 1868 respectively: 1. R. Mylne *Rep. Thames* “There was Seven Inches of Water running over at the Waste Weir at Boulter's Old Lock” 2. H. S. Tanner *Canals & Rail Roads U.S.* 264   “*Waste weir*, a water guage; a cut at the side of a canal by which the surplus water of canals is carried off”. 3. *Chamb. Encycl.* X. 516/2 “There is also the waste-weir, for the purpose of preventing a reservoir embankment being overtopped by floods”.